# How to upload Picture in jmeter with POST request with json data?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have an API with POST method which upload picture.
I want to do it with help of jmeter I have an json which contains the path of image, I tried it replacing with my image parameters but not able to upload it?
Is there any other method with which we can do this?

Json Request:

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="Document1.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\bduguid\OneDrive\Documents\Document1.docx*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sentToId"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is just recording your request using browser or any other tool and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Just make sure that your image is located in JMeter's "bin" folder, otherwise JMeter won't be able to locate it hence the request will fail.

If you are about to build your request manually I believe [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) guide will help.

Comment: Its a mobile app (https)API ,I tried recording it with JMeter's HTTP(S) Test script recorder but not able to record then recorded it with Blazemeter with mobile recorder feaature, API get recorded but the contents (body) do not get record. Any solution for this?

Comment: Anyone come across the above problem?